Does Next.js UI Streaming with React Suspense Boundaries affect SEO and the serialized html the crawlers see?
I have been exploring the Next.js official docs about the UI Streaming feature they have added, They clearly mention that this feature does not affect SEO, but I was wondering what does the crawler see when it visits my page and which part will be included in the SEO? Does it wait for the UI streaming to finish or it just sees the ready-to-serve html that is initially sent from the server to the client?
Given the example below I am wondering that is the page source and the serialized html the crawlers see when they visit our page. Is it the p tag with the placeholder for the suspensed component or is it the end result of the UI streaming?
Is there any way or tool to ensure locally for projects that are not deployed yet?
const HomePage = async () => {
  return (
    <>
      <p>ready to serve html content does not any data to be fetched...</p
      <Suspense fallback={<div>loading...</div>}>
        <Cards /> {// this component performs an async action}
      </Suspense>
    </>
  );
};

export default HomePage;


After studying quite a bit on this subject, I found that what happens behind the scenes is at first the part of the HTML that is ready to be served will be sent from the server, but the connection is kept open. Once data is fetched the other parts will be rendered and sent through the same connection resulting in the streamed HTML to be included in the final result. The other question to answer is whether the crawlers understand this or not. Modern crawlers like google's crawler are able to detect and wait for the streaming to end with sensible timeouts. So in the end if nothing unexpected happens streaming won't hurt your site's SEO and can in deed enhance your TTFB resulting in better scores.

Note that long-running streams can penalize your site.

To further expand my understanding of streaming I went about implementing my own version of server-side rendering and UI streaming using React and Express.js which you can read about at medium.com.
You can test this yourself using Rich Results Text.
Additional Resources:

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/136219/seo-crawlability-impact-of-html-streaming

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/50829

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/loading-ui-and-streaming


